# Building on App Harbor with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, build, appharbor

I am having difficulties getting my first C#/.NET app to go up. I am building it with visual studio 2017, targetFramework="4.6.1", pushing to bit bucket and appHarbor is trying to build from there.

Many many errors like this:

```
Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Web.Helpers.winmd", but it didn't exist.

33 Warning(s)
226 Error(s)
```

Comment: Just a wild guess: app harbor doesn't have x32 .net framework installed? What is your target architecture?

Comment: x64 -- Is there any more information I could give to make this easier to answer? I'm a total noob with the .Net stuff

Comment: looks like something in your project is targeting x32 (thats why it looks for `System.Web.Helpers` assembly in `C:\Program Files (x86)\` folder). You may check your references.